# Remove indentation from an unordered HTML list

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists, spacing

`div.content` that is containing `ul.searchlist` with two `li`s (areas with the *white background*) is not aligning at the left completely as it has some extra spacing (area with the *red background*) and I don't know what is causing it to appear and how to remove it.

*Illustration :*

[image]
*HTML :*

```html
<div id="body-content">
   <h1>Title of</h1>
   <div class="content">
      <p style="margin:0;">Subtitle</p> 
      <ul class="searchlist">
         <li>
            <img src="" title="result" width="110px"/>
            <a href="#">This is a post for  testing CSS</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <img src="" title="result" width="110px"/>
            <a href="#">This is a post for  testing CSS</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```css
#body-content{ float:left; width:700px;background:yellow; }
.content .searchlist{ float:left; width:700px; list-style:none; margin:15px 0 0 0; background:red; }
.content .searchlist li{ padding:10px; float:left; width:688px; background:#fcfcfc; margin-bottom:6px; }
.content .searchlist li img{ float:left; margin-right:10px; }
.content .searchlist li a{ font:bold 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TM3zP/13/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Removing default `padding-left` (this indention ensures  that the markers won't be pushed outside the list ) from `ul` and custom `padding` from `li` should work:

```css
.content ul.searchlist { padding-left : 0; }
.content ul.searchlist li { padding : 10px 0; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TM3zP/14/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not working! And even in your example it seems that its not working!

Comment: Try using his CSS, not adding CSS. @OzzC check out my answer. the `UL` already has as tyle.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is correct so I need to accept the answer, but in my example its still not working!I have my <ul> more at left now, but its not stuck like in your jsfiddle! Really dont understand what I have wrong!

Comment: @OzzC : What browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome, but i already test on firefox and I get the same result!

Comment: @OzzC :It is floated to the left completely below : http://jsfiddle.net/TM3zP/8/ . I've added `body{margin:0}` property. Or maybe `body-content` parent element has `margin` or `padding` properties, so I can't see them in your example.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? I've noticed a bit of cache-control issues on JSFiddle lately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and attention! It worked now :)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `list-style-type:` not `list-style:` and then you need to set it's `margin` and `padding` to `0`, or w/e

```
.content .searchlist {
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/uv3vz/)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should reset the default style sheet before another code. It is the best practice. For example below:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` instead of listing elements... It also causes problems with anything else relying on default behavior.

Comment: We can use * { margin: 0; padding: 0 } too, but I recommend to use the long code. Mostly of the developers, they use that one.

Comment: I've actually never seen anyone use it that way. If you're going to spend the time to list tags, you might as well just add those fixes to the style of that tag. If you're going to default so many, default them all at the beginning of development and re-establish their styles in the CSS. `* { }` will also read in most all browsers. Personally, I just don't use resets as you can do that per-element for your custom site. You shouldn't be coding for other peoples changes to your site to be so easy. Take Facebook for example.

Answer (score 3):

opera next, chrome, safari, and webkit all appear to be adding `40px` of `padding` on the left:

Source:

```
ul, menu, dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

Fix:

```css
#body-content > div > ul {padding-left:0;}
```

Comment: Try using his CSS, not adding CSS. It helps with the learning process.

Comment: Fair point WASqsquatch, I wish there were some easy way to raise awareness of built in developer tools for these people too, It would make thier lives so much easier to know what ctrl+shift+i did.

Comment: Yeah, I'm always `right click -> inspect element` or `ctrl+shift+i` if not just to snoop on websites cool features.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.content .searchList {
   padding-left: 0px;
}
```

`ul` elements start with a bit of `padding` by default.

Comment: Try using his CSS, not adding CSS. It helps with the learning process.

Comment: Edited to be exactly how OP is targeting the element in their CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Set `padding` to `0` :

```
.content .searchlist {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
   float: left;
   list-style: none outside none;
   margin: 15px 0 0;
   width: 700px;
   padding: 0;
}
```